# \hspace{1pt} is equivalent to what spacing commands, in math-mode?

Tags: math-mode, spacing, amsmath, horizontal

I'm using the command `\hspace{1pt}` as a small space in many maths expressions, to adjust the horizontal spacings to my taste.  Frequently, the standard spacing commands `\,` and `\:` are too much, and adding a tiny space is enough. However, I don't like to define an absolute space (1pt) since I may need to change the font size (currently, I'm using 11pt standard fonts).  So what would be a proper replacement to `\hspace{1pt}` in terms of other standard spacing commands?

Here's a silly MWE to play with, party, laugh and have fun:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tensor}

\newcommand*{\psp}{\hspace{1pt}} % \psp for PointSPace.

\begin{document}

Blabla:
\begin{align}
    y &= (\psp x - y \psp), \\
    y &= (x - y).
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: you said in the text that you use 11pt but your example uses 12pt, since the values in the answer totally depend on the font size, that's rather confusing.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, sorry, I edited the MWE.  This code is a modification of my various MWE files!  :-)

Comment: If it's for math mode then use `\mspace{2mu}` (or whatever value you prefer). The `mu` (math unit) will scale with the font.

Comment: @campa, so what size is 2mu?

Comment: `1em=18mu` but the `mu` will scale according to the math style.

Comment: a mu is 1/18 em

Comment: So is it true that 2mu is approximately half a \, ?  I think this is what I would need (i.e. half of the usual \, space)

Comment: 1.5mu is exactly half of \,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are specifically looking at spacing in math. For that, a common spacing measure would be `mu`s. With this in mind, here's an extract from [TeX by Topic](//texdoc.net/pkg/texbytopic) (section **23.6 Mathematical spacing: `mu` glue**):

> Spacing around mathematical objects is measured in `mu` units. A `mu` is 1/18th part
>   of `\fontdimen6` of the font in family 2 in the current style, the "quad" value of the
>   symbol font.

Under the different document class defaults, `1mu` therefore is equivalent to

- `10pt`: `1em` = `10.00002pt`; `1mu` = `0.55554pt`
- `11pt`: `1em` = `10.95003pt`; `1mu` = `0.60832pt`
- `12pt`: `1em` = `11.74988pt`; `1mu` = `0.66666pt`

So, for a (roughly) `1pt` space, you'd need (roughly) `2mu`s under any document class font option. These spaces would scale with the font size, so you could define

```
\newcommand*{\psp}{\hspace{.1\dimexpr1em}}
```

or

```
\newcommand*{\psp}{\mskip2mu}
```

Comment: Wow!  You guys rock!

Answer (score 5):

I would not add space at the points you indicate, so simply not adding space would be my recommendation, however if you add

```
\showthe\dimexpr 1em /18\relax
```

In the text of your document you will get

```
> 0.60834pt.
```

so 1mu math space is .6pt,   a thin space, `\,` is a space of `\thinmuskip` which is 3mu in the standard (and most other) classes so 1.8pt at `\normalsize`.  So perhaps you want `\mskip2mu`

Comment: So I guess that I need to replace my 1pt with 2mu.  What would you suggest as a macro, instead of my \psp in the MWE above?

Comment: @Cham I  would not use anything but if you want to add it it doesn't matter what you call it. `\psp`, `\zzz`, `\extrathinspace`, ...

Comment: I'm not talking about the name, but the macro itself.  What about \newcommand*{\psp}{\mspace{2mu}} ?  So this is half \, right?

Comment: @Cham 2/3 \, not half.

Comment: @Cham `\mspace{2mu}` is probably better latex syntax but requires amsmath package, it is the same as the `\mskip2mu` I put in my answer.